# Change scale of head in lua

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am trying to create a code that will manipulate the size of the players head (or any other bone) from a console command, but i can't get it to work. Here is the code I've got right now:

```
function bighead(ply)
        ply:ManipulateBoneScale( 10, 30 )
end
concommand.Add( "bighead", bighead)
```

Comment: Gonna need some more details. Are you using some sort of game engine? Which one? What is `ply`?

Comment: I am on gmod (Garry's Mod) so ply would be player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you get the BoneID 10?
The BoneID can change from model to model, u need to use `Entity:LookupBone( string boneName )` to get the correct BoneID. And the Name of the Bone is: `ValveBiped.Bip01_Head1`

The second argument to `Entity:ManipulateBoneScale( number boneID, Vector scale )` is a vector. You need to use `Vector( number x=0, number y=0, number z=0 )` to create it.

Now to let users change thier head size locally u need to do the following in a clientside script:

```
concommand.Add( "bighead", function( ply, cmd, args )
  --[[ Number ]] boneID = ply:LookupBone("ValveBiped.Bip01_Head1")
  --[[ Vector ]] scale = Vector(30, 30, 30)
  ply:ManipulateBoneScale(boneID, scale)
end )
```

Please note that I did not tested this, so it can still contain errors, but it should work. Please comment if you found an error...